# Accurately converting date from %tm to date in stata

Tags: date, stata

After appending several datasets, I have dates in the `%tm` format, or YYYYmMM.  I want to convert them into a form where I can split up the month and year in order to make the data quarterly. However, when I try changing them to other date formats, all years appear as 1961. Trying `format %tq` gave incorrect data, as well as `year(date)` and `month(date)` functions. When I convert them to strings, they come up as numbers from 300 to 20000, but then these strange numbers convert back to showing correct year and month when `format %tm` is used. Any idea what is going on and how I can resolve this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and 
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist for guidance on future questions.

Answer (score 2):

You mention several linked problems here without once giving examples showing your exact  code used or your real data. Strictly, that renders your question off-topic here, as there is nothing like a reproducible example in your question. Still, some diagnosis is possible.

The key fallacies here are that

- assigning a particular date display format defines a Stata date
- so changing the display format changes the Stata date type.

Absolutely not! For example, suppose I have a number 42. If I assign it date format `%td`, `%tm`, `%tq` I get shown different dates, but at most one can be correct, as I changed nothing except the display format:

```
. di %td 42
12feb1960

. di %tm 42
1963m7

. di %tq 42
1970q3
```

So, changing the display format without changing the values is often just a recipe for nonsense.

On top of that, if you have monthly dates, `year()` and `month()` can't help without extra functions, as they extract years and months from **daily** dates.

This is tricky, but it is all well documented at `help dates and times`, just in more detail than most people want to read, as you have to skim and skip whatever doesn't apply to your immediate need.

As I understand it, your problem in a nutshell is converting monthly dates to quarterly dates, and for that you don't need to extract month and year as you suppose, although that's one route.

I'd call `dofm()` followed by `qofd()`

```
. di %tm 42
1963m7

. di qofd(dofm(42))
14

. di %tq qofd(dofm(42))
1963q3
```

The effect of those functions is to change (most) values, after which the appropriate display format can be assigned.

As you should see, strategic advice here is to try out solutions by hand using `display`.

If this is off-target, you may need to supply real data and code details, not just mention what you used in an incomplete description.

Note. 20000 is not a plausible monthly date for most Stata users, as it is for some 1600+ years into the future:

```
. di %tm 20000
3626m9
```